# Wifi 6E access point in Linux

Tags: networking, linux-networking, wifi

Context: I'm looking to set up a 6 GHz (Wifi 6E) Access Point in Linux. I have two Intel AX210s (WiFi cards) on two computers.

`nmcli` only supports 2.4GHz + 5GHz

`hostapd` seems to support WiFi 6 but doesn't distinguish it from WiFi 6E, meaning the 6 GHz channels can't actually be used.

Linux has had support for WiFi 6E cards since the 5.11 kernel. Am I missing something here? How can I set up a 6 GHz AP on Linux?

Comment: What hardware are you (thinking of) using? And have you tried either [linux-wifi-hotspot](https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot) (just uses `hostapd` under the hood though) or simply [NetworkManager](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/RealHotspot)?

Comment: Are you planning on putting this into production?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm looking to do the same thing.